# How do I make a discord.js ban all command?

Tags: discord.js

So I'm trying to make a discord ban all command for educational tests but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
  client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.content === '!test') {
   message.guild.members.cache.forEach
  (message.guild.member.ban(user));
}
```

This is what I have roughly created in a few seconds, please help as I have been stuck on this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to ban all members (in Discord.js V13, assuming this is what you're using) you first need to fetch **all** guild members.

```js
let members = await msg.guild.members.fetch({ force: true }); 

members.forEach(member => {
    member.ban({ reason: "ban all" });
});
```

Doing something like this should work.

Comment: Also, you need to enable certain privileged intents in the developer portal for this to work. If you are banning large amounts of users, you might need to watch for ratelimits too.

Comment: I don't believe you need to enable the `Server Members` intent to receive them, I have it disabled on my verified bot and I'm able to get them fine, you just need to enable the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent in your client constructor which I assumed they already did which they might not have. Even if it does return a partial member, they can do `guild.members.ban(partial.id)` instead.

Comment: However yeah, potentially pushing their IDs to an array and using a `setInterval` would be better to avoid ratelimits if they're banning a fairly large server of members

Comment: Don't use `.map()` - use `.each` or `.forEach` since you aren't returning anything

Answer (score 0):

This right here will go through every member of the guild and ban them

```
        let arrayOfIDs = message.guild.members.cache.map((user) => user.id);
        message.channel.send(`Attempting to ban ${arrayOfIDs.length} users`)
        console.log(greenBright(`[>>] Found ${arrayOfIDs.length} members.`))
                for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfIDs.length; i++) {
                    const user = arrayOfIDs[i];
                    const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user);
                    member.ban()
                }
```